# How to get visitors location using Angular 2 or TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I started use get by `ServerVariables["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` by backend server, but it is too slow, I need an Angular or TypeScript solution for this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you wanted to take location from front-end side , we can get the location simply via javascript

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    }
```

This will ask user from browser to share the location , and its done.

[More Details](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp).

In Angular 2 Component implements OnInit , put that code inside ngOnInit

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(){
        if(window.navigator.geolocation){
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setPosition.bind(this));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for your suggestion, Do you know any solution using angular  or typescript instead  ? using Angular 2 components ,thanks.

Comment: Please review my answer again , in angular 2 we can get location by this way,

Hope this will help you.

Comment: just one modification for final solution it is window.navigator

Comment: But it give location sometimes it's not, any hack for this?

Answer (score 12):

Found solution using Vivek example.

```
ngOnInit() {

    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                this.geolocationPosition = position,
                    console.log(position)
            },
            error => {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 1:
                        console.log('Permission Denied');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        console.log('Position Unavailable');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        console.log('Timeout');
                        break;
                }
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Americo Arvani your solution is actually @Vivek-Doshi Solution

Comment: Thanks to remember me, It was @Vivek-Doshi solution indeed